# calculate the area of a domain

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Given a domain
$$
D = \left\{\left(x,y\right) \left\vert\vphantom{\large A^{a}}\right.
\left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right)^{2} \leq 2\left(x^{2} - y^{2}\right),\
x^{2} + y^{2} \geq 1\right\}
$$
how can I calculate the area of $D$ and draw it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Why are you using set notation for a quantity? On the LHS of $\le$ do you mean a quantity of are you simply making a statement that one divides the other. What do you want to plot? You appear to be giving conditions but not showing the function to plot.

Comment: Here is for the graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vurhk1hs4k, I guess you need to somehow find the best parametrisation of that lemniscate.

Comment: I underline @zwim anwser, a parametrization will nicely help you !

Comment: @poetasis there is no function, I need to draw the domain D and calculate ist area

Comment: If you look at the link provided by @zwim, you will see that the area in question is symmetric with respect to the y-axis. Then, you can just integrate the function $f(x,y)=1$ over the area in question on one side of the axis and multiply the result by 2.

Answer (score 1):

The curves in polar coordinates are
$$r^2=2\cos 2t;\;r=1$$
The $S$ area is four times the area in the picture below, given by

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/6} (2 \cos 2t -1)\,dt$$
Should be $S=\sqrt{3}-\frac{\pi }{3}\approx 0.684853$

---

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: Yep, the polar form is really suited to area calculation in this case.